# "There are exactly two values of $x$ for which $P(x)$ is true" formula using logical symbols

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Assuming $P(x)$ is true. The statement: "There are exactly two values of $x$ for which $P(x)$ is true" can be rewritten using logical symbols as follows:

$$\exists x \exists y[(P(x) \wedge P(y) \wedge  x\neq y)\wedge \forall w(P(w) \Rightarrow (w=x)\vee (w=y))]$$

Is this reasoning true, or there is any mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that the subformula $x\neq y$ doesn't lie within the scope of any quantifier, the formula isn't well formed. You're close though. **Edit:** The problem is even more serious than this because in $\forall w(P(w) \Rightarrow (w=x)\vee (w=y))$, the variables $x$ and $y$ aren't quantified either. But the solution is close.

Comment: @GitGud I modified my answer, but still not sure if the approach is good.

Comment: Check the edit to my previous comment. You just need to adjust parentheses to make it correct.

Comment: I'm sorry, on your second edit I didn't notice you swapped $\land$ for $\implies$ right behind $x\neq y$, this isn't correct. Swap the first $\implies$ for $\land$ and you're done.

Comment: Thanks. I already made the swap. Is the expression true with the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. First, try to say *there are two distinct elements that satisfy $P$*. Your approach is pretty close but not right, it should be something like

> There *exist* two elements, $x$ and $y$, such that $P(x)$ and $P(y)$ **and** $x$ is distinct from $y$

This phrase is easier to turn into a formula.

For the "uniqueness" part, you're right, but as @Git Gud notices, the existential quantifiers for $x$ and $y$ should take that part too.

Comment: I already modified my reasoning, not sure if correct though.

Comment: It's completely right. Keep in mind, as GitGud noticed, that $x\neq y$ is actually an abbreviation for $\neg (x=y)$